# Why does my Recaptcha work locally, but fails when using network device?

Tags: asp.net-core, parallels, recaptcha-v3

I'm developing an Angular app that uses reCaptcha when signing in. When I run the app locally in a browser, I am using localhost and everything works properly.

When I run it from my phone connected to the same network, it fails. I am accessing the server via Parallels on a Mac to a Windows VM. I'm using 192.168.1.203 (the VM host IP). The app works fine, but the reCaptcha always fails. I am receiving the error "browser-error".

Does anyone know what this means?

I disabled host checking in the reCaptcha console, but it is sill failing.